Latest MariaDB npm connection issue with server in NodeJS V-20
I have updated the MariaDB NPM version from V-2.1.4 to 3.3.0. And then I have updated the NodeJS Version to 20(LTS). After upgrading, it show the error as Connection timeout.
sequelize npm verison - 6.37.3
If we connect the local server it works. When we tried using the server using IP.
ConnectionError [SequelizeConnectionError]: (conn:80379, no: 45012, SQLState: 08S01) Connection timeout: failed to create socket after 1001ms
    at ConnectionManager.connect (/home/devmachine8/Desktop/BT-DO/BT-DAO/node_modules/sequelize/lib/dialects/mariadb/connection-manager.js:100:17)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
    at async ConnectionManager._connect (/home/devmachine8/Desktop/BT-DO/BT-DAO/node_modules/sequelize/lib/dialects/abstract/connection-manager.js:222:24)
    at async /home/devmachine8/Desktop/BT-DO/BT-DAO/node_modules/sequelize/lib/dialects/abstract/connection-manager.js:174:32
    at async ConnectionManager.getConnection (/home/devmachine8/Desktop/BT-DO/BT-DAO/node_modules/sequelize/lib/dialects/abstract/connection-manager.js:197:7)
    at async /home/devmachine8/Desktop/BT-DO/BT-DAO/node_modules/sequelize/lib/sequelize.js:305:26
    at async Sequelize.authenticate (/home/devmachine8/Desktop/BT-DO/BT-DAO/node_modules/sequelize/lib/sequelize.js:457:5) {
  parent: SqlError: (conn:80379, no: 45012, SQLState: 08S01) Connection timeout: failed to create socket after 1001ms
      at module.exports.createFatalError (/home/devmachine8/Desktop/BT-DO/BT-DAO/node_modules/mariadb/lib/misc/errors.js:90:10)
      at Connection.connectTimeoutReached (/home/devmachine8/Desktop/BT-DO/BT-DAO/node_modules/mariadb/lib/connection.js:1046:24)
      at listOnTimeout (node:internal/timers:575:11)
      at process.processTimers (node:internal/timers:514:7) {
    sqlMessage: 'Connection timeout: failed to create socket after 1001ms',
    sql: null,
    fatal: true,
    errno: 45012,
    sqlState: '08S01',
    code: 'ER_CONNECTION_TIMEOUT'
  },
  original: SqlError: (conn:80379, no: 45012, SQLState: 08S01) Connection timeout: failed to create socket after 1001ms
      at module.exports.createFatalError (/home/devmachine8/Desktop/BT-DO/BT-DAO/node_modules/mariadb/lib/misc/errors.js:90:10)
      at Connection.connectTimeoutReached (/home/devmachine8/Desktop/BT-DO/BT-DAO/node_modules/mariadb/lib/connection.js:1046:24)
      at listOnTimeout (node:internal/timers:575:11)
      at process.processTimers (node:internal/timers:514:7) {
    sqlMessage: 'Connection timeout: failed to create socket after 1001ms',
    sql: null,
    fatal: true,
    errno: 45012,
    sqlState: '08S01',
    code: 'ER_CONNECTION_TIMEOUT'
  }
}

I tried to upgrade the mariadb npm along with nodejs version(LTS).

Should it be the server not running?

@danblack Server is running. But the issue was with the connection made through the local machine.
